# Perché si usa l'articolo determinativo qui?

Tags: grammar, articles

Quando si scrive un'attività come "mangio piselli" l'articolo non è necessario. Certamente posso dire "mangio dei piselli" e anche "mangio i piselli che abbiamo comprato stamattina" ma cambia il senso del frase.

Ma la frase "preparo cena" non è corretta per quello che so e si dice "preparo la cena". "Preparo cena" sembra simile a "mangio piselli" (cioè un'attività generale).

C'è una spiegazione?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Ralph!

Comment: Non so i piselli, ma l'articolo determinativo si usa spesso anche per termini molto generici. Per rimanere vicini ai tuoi esempi relativi al cibo, è usuale dire “Domani andiamo a mangiare il pesce” oppure “Con l'arrosto ci stanno bene le patate”. Il (non-)motivo è che le lingue naturali non sono linguaggi di programmazione e l'uso degli articoli determinativi e indeterminativi (o partitivi o nessun articolo) non è regolato da leggi ferree.

Comment: Concordo con DaG, credo che le ragioni siano idiomatiche. Per esempio "pulisco casa" è corretto, eppure tecnicamente è piuttosto vicino a "preparo cena".

Comment: A me non sembra che _Preparo cena_ non si dica o che sembri sbagliato. Io lo dico proprio così. La questione resta però molto interessante.

Comment: Grazie. Mi domando se sia una cosa associata al partitivo. Si scrive "Guardo la televisione"; "Ascolto la radio".   Per quello che so, NON si puo dire "Guardo delle teleivisioni" neanche "Ascolto della radio" né "Ascolto radio". Un'altro: "Vorrei parlare con gente gentile"... Non si dice "Vorrei parlare con la gente gentile" ma posso dire "vorrei parlare con qualche gente gentile", no?   Insomma, sembra che quando si possa usare il partitivo si possa anche scrivere senza.  Ma come  DaG dice la lingua non è un linguaggio di programmazione. Che ne diresti?    Ralph

Comment: No, “vorrei parlare con qualche gente gentile” non è italiano. “Vorrei parlare con della gente gentile” (ma vedi, sotto, il mio commento a una delle risposte sul fatto che può essere meglio evitare preposizioni + partitivi) o “vorrei parlare con qualche persona gentile”.

Comment: Confermo che per me *preparo cena* è corretto, anche se non troppo comune.

Comment: Per curiosità, in che parte d'Italia si dice “preparo cena”?

Comment: @DaG dalle mie parti suona giusto. Torino

Comment: Io sono di Pavia e a me suona giusto.

Comment: La teoria di @Ralph mi sembra un po' contorta ma dice la cosa giusta: omettere l'articolo è un po' come usare il partitivo. _Vedo gente, faccio cose_ = _Vedo della gente, faccio delle cose_. Ma ci sono altre espressioni dove questo trucco non vale, per esempio _preparar cena_, _far serata_, _cercar moglie_, _attaccar briga_. Non ho una risposta chiara su come mai si siano fissate nell'uso alcune espressioni in questa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Il problema sono le preposizioni articolate come "del, dello, della, degli, dei, delle" quando usate come articoli partitivi (cioè quando si vuole indicare solo una parte, oppure una quantità indeterminata): "ho mangiato del pesce", "ho visto delle persone", "ha avuto dei dispiaceri", "dammi del riso", ecc.

L'italiano infatti, a differenza del francese (da cui ne ha mutuato per imitazione l'uso sovrabbondante) potrebbe farne spesso tranquillamente a meno. Potremmo infatti dire, senza perdere in chiarezza e anzi recuperando un po' di eleganza: "ho mangiato un po' di pesce", "ho visto persone (o alcune persone)", "ho avuto dispiaceri", "dammi un po' di riso", ecc.

L'articolo partitivo in italiano è più naturale quando preceduto da preposizione ("con della", "a delle", "per degli" ecc.). Di questo uso, a differenza dell'altro, ne esistono molti esempi classici da Bembo a Manzoni.

Comment: Potresti dare qualche esempio del caso esposto nell'ultimo paragrafo, per piacere?

Comment: Sul caso preposizione + partitivo mi rispondo da solo: “a degli altri” (Bembo), “con de' begli olmi” (Manzoni), trovati in Serianni (IV.62), che commenta «il suo uso è impossibile [nel caso di + dei] ... oppure non sempre consigliabile»; era censurato dai puristi ottocenteschi come presunto francesismo, ma «va evitato, semmai, per ragioni di chiarezza o di eufonia». Personalmente concordo e non vedo che abbia di “naturale”.

Comment: Maurice sono d'accordo con quello che hai scritto, ma non abbiamo tirato le fila di quello che ho scritto.  Si dice mangio del pesce, un po' di pesce, e semplicemente pesce.  Non si dice mangio il pesce. Mi pare che ci sia una relazione tra questi esempi per quanto riguarda il partitivo, l'articolo determinativo, e il "zero article". Cioè mangio pesce.

Comment: @ Ralph - Però se qualcuno chiede "vuoi mangiare carne o pesce?" si può rispondere "preferisco il pesce", no? A me sembra che l'unico articolo veramente problematico sia quello partitivo quando usato a tappeto come in francese.

Comment: @ DaG Sul fatto che l'uso eccessivo dell'articolo partitivo in italiano sia dovuto all'influenza del francese non credo possano esserci troppi dubbi. Personalmente io lo trovo fastidioso soprattutto quando usato senza preposizione, come Manzoni e altri lo trovo più naturale in italiano quando c'è la preposizione, -- in queste cose si può scegliere.

Comment: Sì, l'uso viene in parte dal francese, ma 250 anni fa: forse è un po' tardi per opporsi a “innovazioni” linguistiche vecchie di qualche secolo. Let's agree to disagree sul fatto che tu lo trovi più “naturale” con la preposizione, mentre è proprio con la preposizione che io lo trovo quasi impronunciabile.

Comment: D'accordo sul fatto che non c'è niente di strano nel dire “mangiare il pesce”, come anche “i vegetariani non mangiano la carne” etc.

Comment: La lingua italiana è influenzata tanto dai dialetti regionali. Per quello che capisco prepare cena non è accettabile in standard italiano. Questo ci fa tornare alla mia domanda all'inizio.  Accetto che una lingua cambia e locuzione è una spiegazione per qualche cosa ma in realità c'e' un sacco di regole nella grammatica italiana anche per le eccezioni di cui molti non ricordano.

Comment: Maurice, sono d'accordo con l'ultimo pezzo.